# Incorrect SHA256 from nodejs crypto

Tags: node.js, sha256, hmac

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

hm = crypto.createHmac("sha256","Some String");
console.log(hm.digest("base64"));
```

Running this gives me:

```
Nd6Q8epsIBG+c/jN6TdnfRNbFWCcB7bI0DYkfyDqf+8=
```

<sup>[(repl)](https://repl.it/repls/NarrowUnwelcomeAtoms)</sup>

But calculating the sha256 at https://approsto.com/sha-generator/ gives me:

```
fw/WRlO6C7Glec7Str83XpFsxgZiEJ7gwLJPCnUMOmw
```

Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Hash`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash) instead of [`Hmac`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hmac).

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
hash.update("Some String");
console.log(hash.digest("base64"));
```

Result:

```
fw/WRlO6C7Glec7Str83XpFsxgZiEJ7gwLJPCnUMOmw=
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between a HMAC and a hash of data?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hmac-and-a-hash-of-data)